# How to convert negated na-adjectives to adverbs?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, negation, na-adjectives

I know when I want to use a な-adjective as an adverb then we have to use に particle instead of な. For example:

> 簡単{かんたん}**に**説明{せつめい}しました。

But I'm curious how to use negated な-adjectives as adverbs. Maybe just should I put the に particle the end of the negated な-adjective? Something like this:

> 簡単{かんたん}**じゃ ない に**説明{せつめい}しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you cannot do this. 簡単じゃないに or (more grammatically correct) 簡単じゃなく is odd in your sentence.

You would have to use antonyms: 簡単に説明した → 詳細に説明した.